# How to set up Google Tag Manager correctly

Tags: frontend, analytics

First time user here, can any please provide information on how to best implement the GTM tag container?

Is it possible to hard code it? Or is the only way to add a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to know: everything you need is in the 
[Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart). Just copy the two pieces in your layout and you are done.

In Craft you are totally free to do everything you want in your frontend templates. The system won't restrict you at all